# Squid Proxy Condition Selection of Parent Proxy

Tags: proxy, conditional-statements, squid

I have purchased 3 proxies, and a squid running in AWS. My case is, for every request I make in my local machine. It must go to request->squid->proxy-> target. While making the request, I want to choose which proxy that the squid to use. Is it possible with squid?

I had an idea to use a custom header like "x-http-proxy: selected-proxy-url", which will be sent with each request so that squid can use it to select the parent proxy.

I don't want to just set like for certain website use this proxy, I wanted it to be choose in the request.

Thanks in advance.